# Why does the negative sign arise in this thermodynamic relation?

Tags: thermodynamics, differentiation

I can't understand why $\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V} \right)_T=-\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T} \right)_V\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_P$. Why does the negative sign arise? I can easily write $\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_T=\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_P$ from the rule of partial derivative, but what's the negative sign for?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is not a simple application of partial derivatives, since the variables that are being held constant vary here, but an instance of the [triple product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule), which says that for any three quantities $x,y,z$ depending on each other, the relation
$$ \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} \right)_x\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y = -1$$
holds.

Answer (score 19):

This all starts from the basic relationship $$dP=\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_VdT+\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_TdV$$Since, at constant pressure, dP=0, if we solve for dT/dV at constant pressure, we obtain:
$$\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_P=-\frac{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_T}{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V}$$

Answer (score 13):

Other answers have given the mathematical reasons, but as these are physical functions it’s always nice to relate back to physical intuition.

Thinking of an ordinary substance – a lump of “stuff”, doesn’t matter whether it’s a solid or a gas or whatever – if you *decrease* the volume available to it, the pressure should go *up*. In fact that is exactly how we physically put a sample under pressure. So the left-hand side should be negative.

On the other hand, if you *increase* the temperature (usually) the pressure should *increase* at constant volume, or alternatively the volume should *increase* at constant pressure.<sup>1</sup> So both of the factors on the right-hand side should be positive.<sup>2</sup>

So we had better include a minus sign, to at least get the signs to match on both sides of the equation.

---

1. If you’re thinking about a material with negative thermal expansion, then both of these factors should instead be negative, but again the right-hand side of the equation ends up positive.
2. To be precise, I have used another identity here: that $(\partial T/\partial V)_P = (\partial V/\partial T)_P^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, this is simply the triple product rule.

It is relatively simple to understand how the minus sign comes about. Suppose you have a fixed amount of money, and you allocate $x$, $y$, and $z$ dollars to three things. Then $(\partial x / \partial y)|_z$ is clearly $-1$, because if you keep $z$ constant, then you need to remove one dollar from $y$ to add one dollar to $x$. Similarly, $(\partial y / \partial z)|_x = (\partial z / \partial x)|_y = -1$, and the product of all three is thus $(-1)^3 = -1$. Note how the total money constraint on the three variables is crucial. In thermodynamics, the constraint between $P$, $V$, and $T$ is provided by an equation of state, such as the ideal gas law.