# Thermodynamic equation of a fluid

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

I have a system whose entropy is specified by three variables: Salinity $S$, pressure$p$, and density$\rho$.

I have the following partial derivative:

\begin{equation}
  (\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial p})_{\rho,S}= -(\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial \rho})_{p,S}(\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial p})_{n,S}
\end{equation}

Where $\eta$ is the specific entropy:

My question is where does the minus sign come from? I though it just was a chain rule but I can not explain this sign.

Thanks

Comment: Should the last derivative be holding eta or n constant?

Comment: This is the [triple product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule); see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/465965/why-does-the-negative-sign-arise-in-this-thermodynamic-relation/466090).

Answer (score 0):

Start with $$d\eta=\left(\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial p}\right)_{\rho}dp+\left(\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial \rho}\right)_pd\rho$$Then set $d\eta$ equal to zero and solve for $d\rho/dp$ (at constant $\eta$).